# One-line closure without return type

Tags: swift

In Swift, if a closure holds only a single statement, it automatically returns the value returned from that single statement.

This does not feel very natural in all cases. Let's look at an example:

```
func StringReturningFunc() -> String {
    return "Test String"
}

// Error: Cannot convert the expressions type '() -> $T0' to type 'String'
let closure: () -> () = {
    StringReturningFunc()
}
```

As you can see, even though the closure should only call a simple function, it tries to automatically return it's return value, which is of type `String`, and does not match the return type `void`.

I can prevent this by implementing the closures body like so:

```
let _ = StringReturningFunc()
```

Which feels incredibly odd.

Is there a better way to do this or is this just something I have to live with?

Comment: I don't understand the point of this, how can you say that closure returns () when your stringreturningfunc explicitly returns a string?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian Just because the closure calls `stringReturningFunc` doesn't mean that it should also return a `String`. Here it should just return nothing, instead of a `String`.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian He's trying to execute the function and discard the return, however there is an implicit `return` statement on single-line closures.

Comment: @NSAddict Ah, now I see what you're trying to do.

Comment: One suprising thing is this example: `class A { func method() {} }; var a: A? = nil; var closure: () -> () = { a?.method() }` It's the same error but caused by mismatch between `Void` and `Void?`.

Comment: @Sulthan It's actually not surprising. `a?.method()` means "If a is not nil, call method on it, if it is nil, just return nil". So the void must be an optional (void is not the same as nil).

Comment: @NSAddict I understand it but that doesn't mean it's obvious.

Comment: @Sulthan Ah sorry, I misunderstood your statement. Yes, same case, in my opinion it shouldn't try to return that value.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The reason this happens is the shorthand for single line expression closures. There is an implicit 'return' in your closure as it is written.

```
let closure: () -> () = {
    StringReturningFunc()
    return
}
```

Writing it like that should work

Comment: Thanks for this tip! If the OP still wants it to be a single line it can be done with `let wrapped : () -> Void = { stringReturningFunc(); return }`

Comment: I see. I do think that this shorthand for closures is not the best design choice. Yes, in some cases you don't have to write the `return` (but in those cases it has a purpose), but then in other ones you do have to (and in those it doesn't have a purpose). Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Is there really no other way to do this without having to explicitly call return?

Comment: You could also do something like `_ = StringReturningFunc()` but I don't think that reads as well

Comment: Couldn't this be fixed in the Swift compiler, if they just detected that the closure was supposed to return Void and therefore didn't try to return the first statement? In all other closures that don't return Void it could use the implicit return.

Comment: @RichardVenable that seems to be an even more complicated rule. I just think this implicit rule is just a bad one. [As PEP20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), the zen of python, says "Explicit is better than implicit". Really, is this rule worth it to not have to type a single word, `return`?

Comment: @SandyChapman In other languages, excluding 'return' is just an implicit 'return void'. You are just used to that convention, and you can get used to this one just as easily. It is good for new languages like Swift, to redefine some of these conventions as software development continues to evolve.

Comment: @RichardVenable You're correct. That is a nice feature in other languages. Leaving out return in that case causes no problems, however, leaving out return in this case causes a confusing compiler error and creates an alternative behaviour whether the term is present or not. This creates an obstruction to quickly learning the language and learning curves are an important part to language design. `() -> Void = { x() }` and `() -> Void = { x(); return }` are different things whereas (in C) `void y() { x(); }` and `void y() { x(); return; }` are identical.

Comment: @SandyChapman The confusing compiler error is a compiler bug that can be fixed, but I still think the convention is good. But in the comment I made which you originally were replying to, I was proposing a way for them to improve it so that `() -> Void = { x() }` and `() -> Void = { x(); return }` are identical. If they detected that the intention is to return Void, they should not assume an implicit return. When not returning Void, Swift's implicit return is great - the alternative in other languages is to generate a compiler error "missing return", but what advantage is that?

Comment: @RichardVenable, I guess we're just going to have to disagree then, which is fine :) Programming is about these sorts of tradeoffs. Some are happy with these sorts of short hands, others aren't. Where some call it elegant design, others say it's overly complex. It's just a difference of opinions. In any case, thanks for the good argument and I think your suggestion is a good one if Apple decides to keep the implicit return.

Comment: Seems to be fixed as of Xcode Beta Version 6.3 (6D520o). “Implicit returns from single-expression closures” now also work for expressions that return something other than Void.

Answer (score 0):

What about this ... ;)

```
@discardableResult func StringReturningFunc() -> String {
    return "Test String"
}

// Error: Cannot convert the expressions type '() -> $T0' to type 'String'
let closure: () -> () = {
    StringReturningFunc()
}
```