# Single unwrap inside block in Swift

Tags: swift, block

This gives me an error:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(MyNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification: NSNotification?) in
    self.variable?.myMethod()
}
```

But this is fine:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(MyNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification: NSNotification?) in
    println()
    self.variable?.myMethod()
}
```

Any idea why and how to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [One-line closure without return type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150400/one-line-closure-without-return-type)

Comment: @doctordoder, it might be similar, but I'n not assigning the block to any variable. Also, I don't need a return statement to make it work, just need to have more than two method calls.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz I think this is a duplicate question because they are caused by same problem, solved by same solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is "implicit returns". Swift assumes that if you have a single expression as the implementation of a closure, then it returns the result of that line of code from the closure. This is a optimization documented in Apple's [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) text (check the last paragraph/bullet list in the Closures intro).

Because of this, if you're required to have a return statement if you don't want to implicitly return from the first statement.

So your code should look like:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(MyNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification: NSNotification?) in
  self.variable?.myMethod()
  return
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very good explanation. I think I heard about this in the videos, but didn't remember.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz You do realize that this is the exact same answer as the one given in the duplicate I flagged right?

Comment: That line wasn't there "Swift assumes that if you have a single expression as the implementation of a closure, then it returns the result of that line of code from the closure"