# Swift - Weird issue with AlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I wanted to make a alert controller with a "custom" action so I looked up how to and found out it was something like this:

```
let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "foo", style: .Default) { (action) -> Void in
   //Some action
}
```

So I did this and the code worked great however:

```
@IBAction func call() {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Call to this number?", message: profilePhone, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
    let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call", style: .Default) { (action) -> Void in
        ()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "tel://\(self.profilePhone)")!)
    }
    alert.addAction(callAction)
    productsView.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

As you can see, I have a random () in the action however if I take this away, the code doesn't work for some reason. It says that Bool can not be converted to Void. Does anybody know how this can happen and what I have done wrong that it would say this?

Thanks

Comment: This is a know problem with single statment closure being inferred as return statment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150400/one-line-closure-without-return-type

Comment: what is profilePhone?

Comment: Just a string, nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks Kirsteins, that clears it up!