# baffled by Swift error - Could not find and overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: swift, closures

Why does this generate error:

[image]

And this doesn't:
[image]

If it matters, live code below:

```
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Resend Verification Email",
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive,
        handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) in
            println("without this line there is a syntax error, why?")
            self._userVerificationService?.triggerEmailVerifiectionResentForUser(PFUser.currentUser())
    }))
```

Comment: Post your code as text using code tags rather than an image.

Comment: Posted as image to demonstrate the error.

Comment: Ok, post the code as code also.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious, but it's hard to tell from a PICTURE of your code. Swift's error messages can be really, really bizarre sometimes. Try breaking your code into smaller bits. Create the action on it's own line and then add it.

Comment: can you post method signature for triggerEmailVerifiectionResentForUser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my guess. Your function, triggerEmailVerifiectionResentForUser has a return value. One-line closures in Swift implicitly take the return value for their one line, so your closure is returning something.

The init for UIAlertAction expects a closure that returns Void. Since your closure implicitly returns something, it does not match the requirement for the init that it return Void.

When the closure has an extra line, it is no longer implicitly taking the return value, so it returns Void like you want it to, thus matching the method signature for UIAlertAction init.

[One-line closure without return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150400/one-line-closure-without-return-type)

Comment: yes, I'm using return to break out of control flow in my closure. That's exactly it!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there is a typo in the spelling of `Verifiection` in `.triggerEmailVerifiectionResentForUser`

EDIT:
Ok. So it wasn't that.

Does this work? :

```
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Resend Verification Email", style: .Destructive) { (action) in self._userVerificationService?.triggerEmailVerifiectionResentForUser(PFUser.currentUser()) })
```

Comment: No, I just spelled the func name incorrectly. Note that with the println() above it works fine. In fact, any line of code preceding that line works. I'm guessing it's something buggy with XCode.

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide an alternative suggestion.